# open node reference links in lightbox/ popup

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I want in my node view pages, node reference links open in popup window or lightbox window.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: do you want to show bubble info, when hovering the link ? or the whole page ?

Answer (score 1):

In Views Use this code in "Rewrite the output of this field"

```
<a href="[path]" rel="lightframe[][My Title]">[title]</a>
```

Note: add  "Node:Path" field before the Rewrite field.

You can also set the width and height of the popup window, see the read-me file in Lightbox2  module folder.

hope you will get idea from the above!!

Comment: I have the same problem and the following code does not work for me - I am using the code below to 'Rewrite the output of a field' in Views.

"[title]"

Any idea what is wrong here?

I have lightbox2 module installed and enabled (D6 Version: 6.22 & lightbox2 Version: 6.x-1.11).

Comment: add the title field and reorder before the rewrite field, if not solved let me know